# I am trying to upgrade spring-security-core version to 5.5.1 and it is giving below exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

**Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration':Initialization of bean failed;nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
<version>5.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
<version>5.0.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
<version>5.0.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
<version>5.0.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>   
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.10.RELEASE</version>   
</dependency>
```

Comment: Don't use specific Spring versions, especially if you are using Spring Boot. Rely on the versions that are associated with the given Spring Boot version. Otherwise, you might end up with compatibility issues.

Comment: If you are planning to upgrade anything, when it comes to the spring bundle, either upgrade everything or do not upgrade anything to avoid issues like this.